# How To get variable output somewhere else in the program | SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, mapkit, geocoding

So I have a program that takes the user's input and turns it into a latitude and longitude coordinate. I want to use that coordinate but I don't really know how to call it anywhere in the program. Any help would be appreciated! The code is below :)

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    @State private var address = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            TextField("Enter Location", text: $address)
            
            Button {
                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                    if((error) != nil){
                        print("Error", error ?? "")
                    }
                    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                        let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
                        print("Lat: \(coordinates.latitude) -- Long: \(coordinates.longitude)")
                    }
                })
            } label: {
                Text("Press For Location")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: you can covert the lat and long value to real location.

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
@State private var result = "result of lat & long"
@State private var address = ""
@State private var lat = 0.0
@State private var long = 0.0
@State private var country = "country name"
@State private var state = "state name"
@State private var zip = "zip code"

var body: some View {
VStack {
    
    //Enter "Florida"
    TextField("Enter Location", text: $address)
    
    //Press button
    Button {
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if((error) != nil){
                print("Error", error ?? "")
            }
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
                print("Lat: \(coordinates.latitude) -- Long: \(coordinates.longitude)")
                //added code
                result = "Lat: \(coordinates.latitude) -- Long: \(coordinates.longitude)"
                lat = coordinates.latitude
                long = coordinates.longitude
            }
        })
    } label: {
        Text("Press For Location")
    }
    
    //result will show "Lat: 29.5449611 -- Long: -81.7627933"
    Text("\(result)")
    
    Spacer()
    
    //Press this button after you pressed the location button
    //it will convert the lat & long to real location
    Button {
        reverseLatLong(lat: lat, long: long)
    } label: {
        Text("Reverse to address")
    }
    Text("\(country)") //United States
    Text("\(state)") //FL
    Text("\(zip)") //32177
}

}
func reverseLatLong(lat:Double, long:Double){
    
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (sub, e) -> Void in
        
        var l: CLPlacemark!
        l = sub?[0]
        
        if let lcountry = l.country {
            country = lcountry
        }

        if let lstate = l.administrativeArea {
            state = lstate
        }
        
        if let lzip = l.postalCode {
            zip = lzip
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Can the result be returned something like the specific lat and long code to use somewhere else in the program to create a map pin? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, but the result you got is already in real lat and long which you can use to pin in the google map of course. You also can convert this lat and long to real location back. I will share you the code by editing my answer. check it out.